# Passing Select Option Value into OnChange Function

Tags: html, forms, html-select, form-submit

I've got an HTML form that I'm using JavaScript to submit with the 'onchange' function of a select control like this:

```
<form action='seeLocation.php?'>Jump To Location: 
    <select onchange='this.form.submit()'>
        <option value='1'>Location1</option>
        <option value='2'>Location2</option>
        <option value='3'>Location3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

The problem is, I need to pass the `<option>`'s value tag into the form's `action` tag such it's actually something like

```
<form action='seeLocation.php?1'>
```

or

```
<form action='seeLocation.php?2'>
```

etc.

Is that possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `onchange` function I think you can do this (haven't tested it):

```
this.form.action="seeLocation.php?"+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;this.form.submit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your html to be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeDropDown(dropdown){
     var location = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
     document.getElementById("form1").action = "seeLocation.php?" + location;
     document.getElementById("form1").submit();
   }
</script>

<form id="form1" name="form1">Jump To Location: 
    <select onchange='changeDropDown(this);'>
        <option value='1'>Location1</option>
        <option value='2'>Location2</option>
        <option value='3'>Location3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

You can also do it inline if you need less verbose code.